# Numerical Solution of $\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}} -5 = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, roots

I am working on a problem at the moment which cuts down to the following question:

How do I get a numerical solution for:

$$\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}} -5 = 0?$$

I've been thinking about using Newton's method here but I am not quite sure how to get a reasonable starting point. Is there any other approach or maybe even just a method that provides me a suitable starting point?

Thank you very much!
FunkyPeanut

Comment: The only solution is $x=0$, are you sure you wrote it correctly?

Comment: You are right! Sorry... I will edit that one. Well that's embarrassing haha :P

Comment: Try bisection (regula falsi) method. Choose the interval [0,10], it should do.

Comment: The solution can be expressed in terms of the Lambert W function, $x = W(\frac{-5}{e^5}) + 5$

Comment: Hmm okay. I have never heared of that bisection method but I'll check that one out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to approximate it, you can show that it is an increasing function and only 1 real solution exists. Then, use the fact that $e^{-5}<<1$ (Well, its $\approx0.006$). Then you can approximately neglect the denominator to $5-5=0$. Hence, the solution is slightly less than $5$. If calculators are allowed, you can easily, check near which value the sign changes.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking about just 1 minute ago! There are many ways that lead to Rome - Thank you :)

Comment: @FunkyPeanut These types of approximations are mostly used in equilibrium in chemistry.

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into the theory, you can often setup a *fixed point iteration* in lieu of the more powerful Newton's method. What I mean is consider the sequence
$$ x_{n+1} = 5(1-\mathrm{e}^{-x_n}). $$

If it converges, it will converge to your answer. And we know from another comment that $x\approx 5$, so that makes an excellent starting guess -- $x_0=5$. Here are the first few terms in the sequence:
$$ \{5, 4.96631, 4.96516, 4.96512, 4.96511\} $$

After only 4 iterations (easily done in a calculator, btw), we have to 5 decimal places the correct answer. Not bad.

Comment: That one is quite amazing! Good to know!

Comment: @Jason: Not bad for positive starting points, though considerably slower compared to the Newton's method. But quite awful for any negative starting point when it rapidly diverges. For an adequate choice of method, most important is the fact that in this case the Newton's method rapidly (quadratically) converges despite the choice of a starting point, no matter whether positive or negative.

Comment: @mkl314, of course that all goes without saying. There had been other discussion already about Newton's method, and I also mentioned this is not as good as Newton's method -- it is only a little bit easier to setup. But in case I misrepresented -- USE NEWTON's METHOD, as its performance will far out class this approach.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to write it in another way

$$x-5=-5\cdot e^{-x}$$

and draw two graphs. Then you see, that you have two solutions, first near $x\in[-1,0]$, second near $5$.